# Serving index.html displays "Internal Error: Missing Template ERR_CONNECT_FAIL" in browser

Tags: node.js, server, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to get my Node server up and running on Ubuntu 14.04. I followed a tutorial from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) to set up nginx and server blocks to serve my content.

I have the server setup correctly, I believe because I can whois *my-site.com* and also ping *my-site.com*. when I visit the web address in the browser, however I get just this error that displays in the page: "Internal Error: Missing Template ERR_CONNECT_FAIL".

I thought that maybe I pointed the nginx server block to the incorrect path, because of of the "Missing Template", but it points to the right file. It is supposed to display a simple index.html file located in /var/www/my-site.com/html.

Here is my server block if this sheds some light on the error:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off;

        root /var/www/my-site.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name my-site.com www.my-site.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

}
```

This file is located in /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site.com and I've copied it to the sites-enabled directory as well.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard error message, and in fact as of this moment nodejs.org is displaying that exact same message. I believe it is generated by a reverse proxy: for example, https://searchcode.com/?q=ERR_CONNECT_FAIL shows that `ERR_CONNECT_FAIL` appears in the [squid reverse proxy software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_(software)). I couldn't find something similar a quick [search through the nginx source code](http://code.openhub.net/search?s=&fp=293460&filterChecked=true).

When I encountered this error message, I was deploying through the digitalocean one-click dokku app and I did not have a domain in `/home/dokku/VHOST`, so it was being assigned a random internal IP address. I accessed it using [domain]:[port]. Hope that gives you a clue.